# ServiceStack.OrmLite MultiThread Error "Field Definition Id was not found"

Tags: multithreading, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

While doing some testing with OrmLite I encountered some problem with multithreading.
In some cases, using my Repo from different threads I encountered a random "concurrency" error on the FieldDefinitionMap.

Reproducing the error is quite easy, just start 10 threads with massive Read / Write operations to get a random error:
'Field Definition Id was not found'

Is very important in order to reproduce the error to use the update/insert functions for the first time on the new threads.

The error comes from the function:

```
public virtual void SetParameterValues<T>(IDbCommand dbCmd, object obj)
```

I was able to solve it putting a lock on the FieldDefinitionMap like follow:

```
namespace ServiceStack.OrmLite
public class ModelDefinition  

public Dictionary<string, FieldDefinition> FieldDefinitionMap
{
get
{
    lock (this) // Locking the get works without problems
    {
        if (fieldDefinitionMap == null)
        {
            fieldDefinitionMap = new Dictionary<string, FieldDefinition>();
            foreach (var fieldDef in FieldDefinitionsArray)
            {
                fieldDefinitionMap[fieldDef.FieldName] = fieldDef;
            }
        }
        return fieldDefinitionMap; 
    }
}
}
```

By the way I do not know if there is any better solution.